# Programmatically creating a notebook containing plots for PDF export

Tags: export, notebooks, pdf-format

In order to save computation results, I want to **programmatically** create some MMA notebooks and export them as PDF files.

It works fine for text:

```
MakeNotebook[] := 
 Module[{nb, nbobj}, nb = NotebookCreate[];
   NotebookWrite[nb,Cell["A Dynamically Created Notebook", "Title"]];
   NotebookWrite[nb, Cell["The date is " <> DateString[], "Text"]];
   nbobj = NotebookGet[nb];
   NotebookClose[nb];
   nbobj]

nb = MakeNotebook[];
Export["~/Temp/test.pdf", nb]
```

But I had some **problems for graphics**:

```
MakeNotebook[] := 
 Module[{nb, nbobj}, nb = NotebookCreate[];
   NotebookWrite[nb,Cell["A Dynamically Created Notebook", "Title"]];

   NotebookWrite[nb, Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2, 2}]]; (* <- not OK *)

   NotebookWrite[nb, Cell["The date is " <> DateString[], "Text"]];
   nbobj = NotebookGet[nb];
   NotebookClose[nb];
   nbobj]
```

does not work as you get `Graphics[{{{{}, {}, Annotation[{...` in your PDF instead of your plot.

**So my question is: how to include graphics**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It took me some time to find a working solution:

```
MakeNotebook[] := 
 Module[{nb, nbobj}, nb = NotebookCreate[];
   NotebookWrite[nb,Cell["A Dynamically Created Notebook", "Title"]];

   NotebookWrite[nb,Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[Plot[Sin[x],{x,-2,2}]]],"Print"]]; (*<-OK*)

   NotebookWrite[nb, Cell["The date is " <> DateString[], "Text"]];
   nbobj = NotebookGet[nb];
   NotebookClose[nb];
   nbobj]

nb = MakeNotebook[];
Export["~/Temp/test.pdf", nb]
```

The right line was:

`NotebookWrite[nb,Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[Plot[Sin[x],{x,-2,2}]]],"Print"]];`

---

**The result is:**

[image]

Comment: You could also use `Paste[nb, Plot[Sin[x],{x,-2,2}]]`.

Comment: @CarlWoll Thanks! That seems simpler effectively. Maybe you can write an answer I will be happy to accept it.